# Automatically aggregate German ZIP codes by the first two digits in a shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, zip-codes

I have a [shapefile which contains all German Zip-Codes](http://arnulf.us/PLZ) in a a five-digit format (e.g. 80637). For what I intend to do, this is way to much detail. I would like to aggregate all Zip-Code areas by the first two digits (e.g. 80).

[image]

My approach is ordering ZIP codes in the QGIS attributes table numerically, then selecting them manually, then joining them. This is somewhat cumbersome I'll have to do this a hundert time.

Is there a way of doing this programmatically? I tried automate this process following [this instruction](http://qgissextante.blogspot.de/2013/04/geoscripting-in-sextante.html), but I failed at importing sextante.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

create a new field and copy the first two digits from the left using the [field calculator](https://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user%5fmanual/working%5fwith%5fvector/field%5fcalculator.html)

-> for text, you can use (left(fieldname,2)) in the field calculator. With numeric field you can use floor(fieldname/1000)

dissolve your polygons based on this new field

-> this command is in vector -> geometry -> dissolve

Comment: I suggest to use text fields. Otherwise the leading 0 in East German postal codes gets lost.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and saving me a lot of time. The field calculator is a mighty tool I've never noticed/used before. I think this solution can be applied to many problems.

Comment: is it possible to export the 2 digit zip code layer as it's own 2 digit zipcode shapefile?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. maybe you could ask a question with some more details.